# Magento product attribute quantities

Tags: magento, attributes, product

In Magento (1.7.0.2) If i have a product, e.g. iPod and I add a custom attribute to this product e.g. colour, (red, blue, green), can I define the quantity of stock that is availble for each colour?

E.g. 10 red, 1 blue and 3 green, as opposed to 14 iPods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a configurable product for this. Then you can combine multiple products to be a single product on the webpage based on one or more attributes. In the admin you can manage the stocks for each individual product.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product